# PKI integration in MAC OS

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, macos

I have setup an ejbca pki and integrated certificates in MAC OS for S/MIME signing and encrypting. I have also set up a CRL distribution point and put the CRL online available on an HTTP server.
Unfortunately, it appears that when I revoke a certificate and update the CRL, neither outlook or Mail clients seem to detect that the certificate is actually revoked.
Does anyone has tips or advice that I could use to debug this?

the only option I found in MAC OS to check for CRL is in keychain options:
preferences -> certificates : 
OCSP: check if certificates needs it
CRL: check if certificate needs it
priority: OCSP

what else should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked after clearing the MAC OS CRL/OCSP cache which is located in
/private/var/db/crls/.